# react pass function as prop without jsx

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, create-react-app

Hello i'm in a situation where i can use React only with CDN and i don't want to load jsx so i'm trying the hardcore mode, i'm trying to pass a function as prop but i get an error

This is my Code

```
 const r = React.createElement;
        class Button extends React.Component{
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this)
            }
            clickMe = () => {
                this.props.clic()
            }
            render() {
                return r("button", { onClick: this.clickMe }, 'CLICK')
            }
        }
        class Cont extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
                this.handleClic = this.handleClic.bind(this)
                this.state = {
                x :"Hello World"}
            }
            handleClic() {
                this.setState({
                    x : "HELLO CHANGED"
                })
            }
                render() {
                    return r('div',
                       
                        this.state.x,
                        r(Button, {clic:this.handleClic})
                       
                    );
                }
        }

        class Wrapper extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return r('div',
                    null,
                    r(Cont),
                    r(Cont),
                    r(Cont),
                    r(Cont),
                    r(Cont),
                    r(Cont),
                )
            }
        }
```

This is the error

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `0`
    in div (created by Cont)
    in Cont (created by Wrapper)
    in div (created by Wrapper)
    in Wrapper
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature of [`createElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Where `props` should be an object. `this.state.x` is a string.

Maybe you wanted to pass `this.state`?

Comment: No I want to pass the function handleClic to the component Button

Comment: @vUes The function is not the problem. You passed `this.state.x` to the `div`.

Comment: yea i need to pass that too to change the text when i click the button (if i put the handleclick directly on the div without passing it to the button i don't get this error)